# How to solve the following problem on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, differentiation

a(x) here is a type of equation used in signal

```
Let
y(x) = x^3 + x^2 + x + 1
a(x) is inputed by the user so for example if user inputs
a(x) = D2 + D + 6
y(x)*a(x) = D2(x^3 + x^2 + x + 1) + D(x^3 + x^2 + x + 1) + 6(x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)
here D2(x^3 + x^2 + x + 1) = 6x + 2 and D(x^3 + x^2 + x + 1) = 3x^2 + 2x + 1
So D is differentiation and D2 is double differential
```

So i want to know how i would do something like this on MATLAB

Answer (score 0):

Use Matlab symbolic computation toolbox https://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic.html

```
Calculus
Evaluate exact analytical solutions for definite or indefinite integral, 
calculate derivatives of symbolic expressions or functions, 
and approximate functions using series expansions.
```